# How can I get/run the 'gsharp' GUI wrapper for the csharp REPL in Mono?

Tags: c#, mono, read-eval-print-loop

[Mono's C# REPL](http://www.mono-project.com/CsharpRepl) has on its page this bit of info:

> A GUI version of this tool is called gsharp and is available when you install the mono-tools package

The same bit of info is mentioned in the [Mono 2.2 release notes](http://www.mono-project.com/Release_Notes_Mono_2.2).

However, while I've installed the 30-day trial of mono-tools (vsix for VS2010), and the normal Mono for Windows package (2.10.8), I don't see anything in either that lets me open the window from the screen shot "C# InteractiveBase Shell".  I also can't find any files on my disk (after installing both) starting with 'gsharp'

Did 'gsharp' move somewhere else?

I know the source is available as part of the mono-tools repo @ https://github.com/mono/mono-tools/tree/master/gsharp, but just trying to find a 'release build' to use instead if possible. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mono-tools for Visual Studio is a former product of Novell, which is discontinued (which Xamarin doesn't offer either).

I recommend you try to install Mono for Windows official bundle from http://www.mono-project.com/ If that installer doesn't include it, I recommend you compile mono-tools yourself, shouldn't be very hard with cygwin or mingw32.

PS: Note, "Mono tools for Visual Studio" and the "mono-tools" module (https://github.com/mono/mono-tools) are two different things.

(BTW, Mono 2.2 is very old. Only accept Mono 2.10.x or higher nowadays)

Comment: Sorry for not including that bit of info - I had installed 2.10.8 before installing mono-tools (the only 'mono-tools' I could find to install :) - since you mentioned that the 'mono tools for Visual Studio' is different, and therefore I installed the wrong 'mono-tools', is there a place with builds of the 'right' mono-tools?  There's definitely not one @ https://github.com/mono/mono-tools/downloads :)

Comment: Did you install the official Mono for Windows installer? It may come with Mono.CSharp and gsharp already...

Comment: I downloaded the stable build from http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html - specifically, http://download.mono-project.com/archive/2.10.8/windows-installer/1/mono-2.10.8-gtksharp-2.12.11-win32-1.exe - it came with csharp (the text-based REPL, installed under Mono-2.10.8\bin) which works fine, just not gsharp.  It even comes with a sqlsharp, just not gsharp :)